# Eclipse CDT -- ESP8266 -- espressif hello_world_cpp example

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, esp8266

I have been using the Arduino IDE for esp8266 coding, but would like to move to a little more powerful environment.  I'm making my first foray into the Eclipse CDT environment with a MinGW GCC toolchain.

EDIT -- I do have this Eclipse C Arduino plugin installed:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-c-ide-arduino

However, on my first attempt to get a project working, I'm running into a lot of issues trying to get everything compiled and linked.  I've chosen the hello_world_cpp example from the Espressif SDK.  I've corrected a number of issues I've run into, but can't seem to figure out how to get past the linking problem below.  Output is copied below after the main project code.

Can you guys give any pointers on where I might start looking on this problem?  It looks like I'm missing a library, but for the life of me I can't find the library that contains the missing functions.  Let me know if there's further information that would be useful.

Here is the main cpp file:

```
/*
    The hello world c++ demo
*/

#include <ets_sys.h>
#include <osapi.h>
#include <os_type.h>
#include <gpio.h>

#define DELAY 1000 /* milliseconds */

// =============================================================================================
// C includes and declarations
// =============================================================================================
extern "C"
{
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include <user_interface.h>

void *pvPortMalloc( size_t xWantedSize );
void vPortFree( void *pv );
void *pvPortZalloc(size_t size);

// declare lib methods
extern int ets_uart_printf(const char *fmt, ...);
void ets_timer_disarm(ETSTimer *ptimer);
void ets_timer_setfn(ETSTimer *ptimer, ETSTimerFunc *pfunction, void *parg);
void ets_timer_arm_new(ETSTimer *ptimer,uint32_t milliseconds, bool repeat_flag, bool);

#define os_malloc   pvPortMalloc
#define os_free     vPortFree
#define os_zalloc   pvPortZalloc

}//extern "C"

// =============================================================================================
// These methods shall be defined anywhere.
// They are required for C++ compiler
// =============================================================================================
void *operator new(size_t size)
{
   return os_malloc(size);
}

void *operator new[](size_t size)
{
   return os_malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void * ptr)
{
   os_free(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void * ptr)
{
   os_free(ptr);
}

extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual(void) __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
extern "C" void __cxa_deleted_virtual(void) __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
extern "C" void abort()
{
   while(true); // enter an infinite loop and get reset by the WDT
}

void __cxa_pure_virtual(void) {
  abort();
}

void __cxa_deleted_virtual(void) {
  abort();
}

// =============================================================================================
// Example class. It show that the global objects shall be initialyzed by user
// (see user_init method)
// =============================================================================================

class A
{
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    A()
    : a(5)
    , b(6)
    {
    }

    A( int k, int m )
    : a(k)
    , b(m)
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        ets_uart_printf( "a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b );
    }
};

// =============================================================================================
// global objects
// =============================================================================================

LOCAL os_timer_t hello_timer;
A a;


// =============================================================================================
// Pointers to the constructors of the global objects
// (defined in the linker script eagle.app.v6.ld)
// =============================================================================================

extern void (*__init_array_start)(void);
extern void (*__init_array_end)(void);

// Initialyzer of the global objects
static void do_global_ctors(void)
{
    void (**p)(void);
    for (p = &__init_array_start; p != &__init_array_end; ++p)
            (*p)();
}

// =============================================================================================
// User code
// =============================================================================================

LOCAL void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR hello_cb(void *arg)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    ets_uart_printf("Hello World #%d!\r\n", counter++);
    a.print();
}


/******************************************************************************
 * FunctionName : user_rf_cal_sector_set
 * Description  : SDK just reversed 4 sectors, used for rf init data and paramters.
 *                We add this function to force users to set rf cal sector, since
 *                we don't know which sector is free in user's application.
 *                sector map for last several sectors : ABBBCDDD
 *                A : rf cal
 *                B : at parameters
 *                C : rf init data
 *                D : sdk parameters
 * Parameters   : none
 * Returns      : rf cal sector
*******************************************************************************/
extern "C" uint32 ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_rf_cal_sector_set(void)
{
    enum flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
    uint32 rf_cal_sec = 0;

    switch (size_map) {
        case FLASH_SIZE_4M_MAP_256_256:
            rf_cal_sec = 128 - 8;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_8M_MAP_512_512:
            rf_cal_sec = 256 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 512 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 1024 - 5;
            break;

        default:
            rf_cal_sec = 0;
            break;
    }

    return rf_cal_sec;
}

extern "C" void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_rf_pre_init(void)
{
}

extern "C" void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_init(void)
{
    do_global_ctors();
    // Configure the UART
    uart_init(BIT_RATE_115200, BIT_RATE_115200);
    ets_uart_printf("System init...\r\n");

    // Set up a timer to send the message
    // os_timer_disarm(ETSTimer *ptimer)
    os_timer_disarm(&hello_timer);
    // os_timer_setfn(ETSTimer *ptimer, ETSTimerFunc *pfunction, void *parg)
    os_timer_setfn(&hello_timer, (os_timer_func_t *)hello_cb, (void *)0);
    // void os_timer_arm(ETSTimer *ptimer,uint32_t milliseconds, bool repeat_flag)
    os_timer_arm(&hello_timer, DELAY, 1);

    ets_uart_printf("System init done.\r\n");
}
```

And build output:

```
19:44:02 **** Rebuild of configuration Default for project hello_world_cpp ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -I../include "-IC:\\Espressif\\ESP8266_SDK\\include" -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "driver\\uart.o" "..\\driver\\uart.c" 
In file included from C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/ets_sys.h:12:0,
                 from ..\driver\uart.c:12:
..\driver\uart.c: In function 'uart_config':
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/eagle_soc.h:250:38: warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|' [-Wparentheses]
                                      &  (~(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC<<PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC_S))  \
                                      ^
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/eagle_soc.h:50:98: note: in definition of macro 'WRITE_PERI_REG'
 #define WRITE_PERI_REG(addr, val) (*((volatile uint32_t *)ETS_UNCACHED_ADDR(addr))) = (uint32_t)(val)
                                                                                                  ^~~
..\driver\uart.c:36:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PIN_FUNC_SELECT'
         PIN_FUNC_SELECT(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_GPIO2_U, FUNC_U1TXD_BK);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\driver\uart.c:12:0:
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/ets_sys.h:61:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ets_isr_attach' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     ets_isr_attach(ETS_UART_INUM, (func), (void *)(arg))
     ^
..\driver\uart.c:39:9: note: in expansion of macro 'ETS_UART_INTR_ATTACH'
         ETS_UART_INTR_ATTACH(uart0_rx_intr_handler,  &(UartDev.rcv_buff));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/ets_sys.h:12:0,
                 from ..\driver\uart.c:12:
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/eagle_soc.h:250:38: warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|' [-Wparentheses]
                                      &  (~(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC<<PERIPHS_IO_MUX_FUNC_S))  \
                                      ^
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/eagle_soc.h:50:98: note: in definition of macro 'WRITE_PERI_REG'
 #define WRITE_PERI_REG(addr, val) (*((volatile uint32_t *)ETS_UNCACHED_ADDR(addr))) = (uint32_t)(val)
                                                                                                  ^~~
..\driver\uart.c:41:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PIN_FUNC_SELECT'
         PIN_FUNC_SELECT(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_U0TXD_U, FUNC_U0TXD);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\driver\uart.c:44:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'uart_div_modify' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     uart_div_modify(uart_no, UART_CLK_FREQ / (UartDev.baut_rate));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\driver\uart.c: In function 'uart0_tx_buffer':
..\driver\uart.c:163:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'uart_tx_one_char' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         uart_tx_one_char(buf[i]);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\driver\uart.c:12:0:
..\driver\uart.c: In function 'uart_init':
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/ets_sys.h:67:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ets_isr_unmask' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     ets_isr_unmask((1<<inum))
     ^
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/ets_sys.h:76:5: note: in expansion of macro 'ETS_INTR_ENABLE'
     ETS_INTR_ENABLE(ETS_UART_INUM)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\driver\uart.c:182:5: note: in expansion of macro 'ETS_UART_INTR_ENABLE'
     ETS_UART_INTR_ENABLE();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\driver\uart.c:13:0:
C:\Espressif\ESP8266_SDK\include/osapi.h:13:26: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ets_install_putc1' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 #define os_install_putc1 ets_install_putc1
                          ^
..\driver\uart.c:185:5: note: in expansion of macro 'os_install_putc1'
     os_install_putc1((void *)uart1_write_char);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
g++ "-IC:\\Espressif\\ESP8266_SDK\\include\\" -I../include -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "user\\user_main.o" "..\\user\\user_main.cpp" 
g++ -Lc:/MinGW/msys/1.0/lib "-LF:\\Espressif\\lib" -o hello_world_cpp "driver\\uart.o" "user\\user_main.o" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:\Espressif\lib/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:\Espressif\lib\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:\Espressif\lib/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:\Espressif\lib\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
driver\uart.o: In function `uart_config':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:39: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:39: undefined reference to `ets_isr_attach'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:44: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:44: undefined reference to `uart_div_modify'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:46: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:46: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:46: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:46: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:57: undefined reference to `UartDev'
driver\uart.o: In function `uart0_tx_buffer':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:163: undefined reference to `uart_tx_one_char'
driver\uart.o: In function `uart_init':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:178: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:180: undefined reference to `UartDev'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:182: undefined reference to `ets_isr_unmask'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../driver/uart.c:185: undefined reference to `ets_install_putc1'
user\user_main.o: In function `hello_cb':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:135: undefined reference to `ets_uart_printf'
user\user_main.o: In function `ZN1A5printEv':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `ets_uart_printf'
user\user_main.o: In function `user_rf_cal_sector_set':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:155: undefined reference to `system_get_flash_size_map'
user\user_main.o: In function `do_global_ctors':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:124: undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:124: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:124: undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
user\user_main.o: In function `user_init':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:194: undefined reference to `ets_uart_printf'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:198: undefined reference to `ets_timer_disarm'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:200: undefined reference to `ets_timer_setfn'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:202: undefined reference to `ets_timer_arm_new'
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:204: undefined reference to `ets_uart_printf'
user\user_main.o:C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:137: undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc'
user\user_main.o: In function `Znaj':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc'
user\user_main.o:C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `vPortFree'
user\user_main.o: In function `ZdaPv':
C:\Espressif\examples\ESP8266\hello_world_cpp\Default/../user/user_main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `vPortFree'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

19:44:03 Build Finished (took 890ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears CDT is running `gcc` for host development as opposed to the gcc cross-compiler needed for generating code for your Arduino board.

Are you using "vanilla" CDT, or have you using Arduino plug-ins for Eclipse.

Two to consider:

- http://eclipse.baeyens.it/
- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-c-ide-arduino

Comment: For some reason I thought CDT referred to the second plugin.   I looked at both and liked the eclipse-c-ide-arduino better than the sloeber version.  I have this one installed:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-c-ide-arduino